# Can I integrate SourceSafe / VSS with SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, visual-sourcesafe, database-versioning

How are the SQL objects managed with VSS?

Can I integrate SourceSafe / VSS with SQL Server 2005?

I want versioning in my SQL schemas.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from VSS being a total train wreck, if you want to store your schema in source control, one possible approach is to store the object creation script for each database object as a separate file in source control. That way, you can update individual parts of the schema easily. So you have a script for each table, trigger, index, procedure etc. As part of your build process these can be pulled together into a single script for ease of application to the target database.

Comment: Total train wreck: my experience as well.

Comment: Although this approach works, it quickly becomes a maintenance hazard, as you need to keep up with the changes. Think of it as an additional task.

Comment: @Wisdom if you have some stringent QA processes in place, it doesn't need to be a hazard, but I'd love to hear of a better approach if you have one!

Comment: @ninesided: agreed but my point is that one needs to be very careful & remember to script every change or else you will have versionitis, u know what i mean.

Comment: @Wisdom: I know exactly what you mean ;-)

Comment: @BhejaFry That's why you don't let developers make changes in a production environment - this can enforce all changes go through source control.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize tools like SQL Compare from Red Gate which will allow you to create schema, object per file, and then maintain the state of the files with VSS.  I am currently trying to push that in my organization.

Answer (score 0):

We've just added Visual Source Safe support to SQL Source Control, providing source control integrated into SQL Server Management Studio. This is in early access at the moment so please sign up for the early access build and tell us what you think.

More detail is available here:
http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/viewtopic.php?t=12265